# Spring Boot security sign-in 403 Forbidden error question

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I am having some issue on my Spring security sign-in. Signup works fine with no error but only sign-in returns 403 forbidden error.
I tried add http.httpBasic() and it returns 401 error.

I have http.csrf().disable() in the SecurityConfig.java but it still doesn't work even it's permitAll() condition. I am stuck in this problem for days :/ I tried every single solution that I googled but nothing worked.

Here is SecurityConfig.java

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.cors();//cross-origin-resource-sharing
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);


        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/authentication/**").permitAll()//login and register pre-path
                .anyRequest().permitAll();

        http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthorizationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthorizationFilter jwtAuthorizationFilter()
    {
        return new JwtAuthorizationFilter();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception
    {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder()
    {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer()
    {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer()
        {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry)
            {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedOrigins("*")
                        .allowedMethods("*");
            }
        };
    }
```

I think from this jwtAutheorizationFiler.java cause the issue if the Security config is fine:

```
public class JwtAuthorizationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter
{
    @Autowired
    private JwtProvider jwtProvider;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        Authentication authentication = jwtProvider.getAuthentication(request);

        if (authentication != null && jwtProvider.isTokenValid(request))
        {
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

SecurityUtils.java

```
public class SecurityUtils
{

    public static final String ROLE_PREFIX = "ROLE_";
    public static final String AUTH_HEADER = "authorization";
    public static final String AUTH_TOKEN_HEADER = "Bearer";
    public static final String AUTH_TOKEN_PREFIX = AUTH_TOKEN_HEADER + " ";

    public static SimpleGrantedAuthority convertToAuthority(String role)
    {
        String formattedRole = role.startsWith(ROLE_PREFIX) ? role : ROLE_PREFIX + role;

        return new SimpleGrantedAuthority(formattedRole);
    }
    public static String extractAuthTokenFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        String bearerToken = request.getHeader(AUTH_HEADER);

        if(StringUtils.hasLength(bearerToken) && bearerToken.startsWith(AUTH_TOKEN_PREFIX))
        {
            return bearerToken.substring(7);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

CustomUserDetailService.java :

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService
{
    private LoginService loginService;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException
    {
        Login login = loginService.findByUsername(username)
                .orElseThrow(()-> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with username: "+ username));

        Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = Set.of(SecurityUtils.convertToAuthority(login.getRole().name()));

        return UserPrincipal.builder()
                .login(login)
                .id(login.getId())
                .username(login.getUsername())
                .password(login.getPassword())
                .authorities(authorities)
                .build();
    }
}
```

AuthenticationController.java

```
  @Autowired
    private AuthenticationService authenticationService;

    @Autowired
    private LoginService loginService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtRefreshTokenService jwtRefreshTokenService;

    @PostMapping("sign-up")//api/authentication/sign-up
    public ResponseEntity<?> signUp(@RequestBody Login login)
    {
        if(loginService.findByUsername(login.getUsername()).isPresent())
        {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(loginService.saveLogin(login), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @PostMapping("sign-in")//api/authentication/sign-in
    public ResponseEntity<?> signIn(@RequestBody Login login)
    {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(authenticationService.signInAndReturnJWT(login), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

AuthenticationServiceImple.java

```
@Service
public class AuthenticationServiceImpl implements AuthenticationService
{
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private JwtProvider jwtProvider;

    @Autowired
    private JwtRefreshTokenService jwtRefreshTokenService;

    @Override
    public Login signInAndReturnJWT(Login signInRequest)
    {
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(signInRequest.getUsername(), signInRequest.getPassword())
        );

        UserPrincipal userPrincipal = (UserPrincipal) authentication.getPrincipal();
        String jwt = jwtProvider.generateToken(userPrincipal);

        Login signInUser = userPrincipal.getLogin();
        signInUser.setAccessToken(jwt);
        signInUser.setRefreshToken(jwtRefreshTokenService.createRefreshToken(signInUser.getId()).getTokenId());

        return signInUser;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please add the exception stacktrace also in the question details?

Comment: And you have enabled debug logs? And they say?